# does foreachRDD keep order reading a kafka topic with 1 partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I wonder this simple question:
does foreachRDD keep order reading a kafka topic with 1 partition?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else wonder the same question, the answer is yes